# Gitlab / Rails error during updating and reinstall

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version, rake, gitlab, assets

I am on Debian.

I installed Gitlab following this:
https://people.debian.org/~praveen/gitlab/README

But, I don't know why, my assets (CSS, JS) were often broken...

So, I executed `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` in my `usr/share/gitlab` folder.

But today, I received the following error:
`Could not find gem 'rails (>= 4.2.7.1, ~> 4.2)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run bundle install to install missing gems.`

I did it and received a second error...
`An error occurred while installing rake (12.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that gem install rake -v '12.0.0' succeeds before bundling.`

I did all that I found here... But nothing worked. So I uninstall rail (which uninstalled gitlab...)...

I reinstall rails and doing "rails --version" responded 4.2.7.1...

So I reinstall gitlab...

And all is broken... When I do rails --version it answer the first Error:
`Could not find gem 'rails (>= 4.2.7.1, ~> 4.2)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run bundle install to install missing gems.`

If someone has an idea? Thank you so much.

Comment: run `rails -v` in your terminal and check what version of rails it shows. Looks like there is no rails installed on your system

Comment: rails -v answer me `Rails 4.2.7.1` but if I try to do a `sudo apt-get upgrade` I obtain `Paramétrage de gitlab (8.13.11+dfsg1-3) ...
Creating/updating gitlab user account...
Making gitlab owner of /var/lib/gitlab...`
**Could not find gem 'rails (>= 4.2.7.1, ~> 4.2)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.**
`dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet gitlab (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` :-\

Comment: `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`  means there are broken packages or source file is corrupt. This happens when something doesn't get installed properly. Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` these will tell you what package is broken and then remove and re-install those packages.

Comment: Always the same error :-\ `Could not find gem 'rails (>= 4.2.7.1, ~> 4.2)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.`

Comment: First of all I am not able to understand why you need separate Rails installation for gitlab (gitlab package includes it). Second, your installation didn't go well, some packages are missing that's why you are repeatedly getting these errors. You should first install Ruby on your system either using rvm or source. GitLab requires Ruby (MRI) 2.3. Support for Ruby versions below 2.3 (2.1, 2.2) will stop with GitLab 8.13. And lastly you should install gitlab on your machine following the official instructions at gitlab website about.gitlab.com/downloads 
What is your ruby version and path?

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to install Gitlab on Debian/Ubuntu:

**METHOD 1: Installation from source**

**Installing dependencies:**

```
# run as root!
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install sudo -y
```

Then required packages(needed to compile Ruby and native extensions to Ruby gems):

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential zlib1g-dev libyaml-dev libssl-dev libgdbm-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev curl openssh-server checkinstall libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libicu-dev logrotate python-docutils pkg-config cmake
```

and If you want to use Kerberos for user authentication, then install libkrb5-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev
```

**Install right version of git**

```
# Install Git
sudo apt-get install -y git-core

# Make sure Git is version 2.8.4 or higher
git --version
```

If git is too old, remove and install the right version.

**Install recommended mail server:**

```
sudo apt-get install -y postfix
```

**Install Ruby:**

First remove the old version

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby
```

Download and compile ruby:

```
mkdir /tmp/ruby && cd /tmp/ruby
curl --remote-name --progress https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.3.tar.gz
echo '1014ee699071aa2ddd501907d18cbe15399c997d  ruby-2.3.3.tar.gz' | shasum -c - && tar xzf ruby-2.3.3.tar.gz
cd ruby-2.3.3
./configure --disable-install-rdoc
make
sudo make install
```

Install the bundler gem

```
sudo gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

**Install Go:**

```
# Remove former Go installation folder
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go

curl --remote-name --progress https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.5.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
echo '43afe0c5017e502630b1aea4d44b8a7f059bf60d7f29dfd58db454d4e4e0ae53  go1.5.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz' | shasum -a256 -c - && \
  sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.5.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/go/bin/{go,godoc,gofmt} /usr/local/bin/
rm go1.5.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

**Install node:**

```
# install node v7.x
curl --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# install yarn
curl --location https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash -
```

**Add User**

```
sudo adduser --disabled-login --gecos 'GitLab' git
```

and then install database PostgreSQl(recommended) or Mysql and configure it.

Then install redis and gitlab as mentioned here [Installing gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html#7-redis)

The other way to install is to:

**METHOD 2: Install using GitLab package server**

After installing **dependencies** and **ruby** as mentioned above

Step 1: `sudo apt-get install curl openssh-server ca-certificates postfix`

Step 2: Add the GitLab package server and install the package

```
curl -sS https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce
```

Step 3: Configure and start GitLab

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Step 4: Browse to the hostname and login

References: https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/ and
            https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/installation.html